# NetBeans missing code completion option for C

Tags: netbeans, code-completion

I just installed NetBeans on my Windows machine (usually use Linux), and when I open my C/C++ projects, they build well but none of the syntax is recognized and highlighted. `#include`, for example, just stays black. Same goes for everything else other than basic C data types (`float`, `int`, etc.). When in Options->Editor->Code Completion, the only language I see in the drop-down menu is HTML, but there's an option to import one. Is there a way of fixing this? I tried uninstalling and reinstalling.

Answer (score 4):

You have to install the c/c++ plugin in "tool"-> "plugin" -> "available plugin".
After restarting NetBeans then still in plugin in the tab "installed" you should see c/c++ and it should be active.